# Display date in roman numerals

Tags: javascript

I need to display the current date on my webpage using jquery or javascript, sounds easy right?

However I would like the date to be displayed in roman numerals (d/m/y format). eg: 13/10/2013 to be displayed as XIII.X.MMXIII

I have been trying for a few days now but everything I try won't work. I have a fairly limited knowledge of jquery and javascript, I only know how to do normal date. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
    document.write(month + " . " + day + " . " + year)
    //-->
  </script>
```

If anyone can help me to display the date in roman numerals it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not about the dates, it's about converting month, day and year to Roman numerals. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083037/convert-a-number-into-a-roman-numeral-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: here is a fiddle based on @DiegoBasch link: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/DAuTn/

Comment: Thank you guys, @naveen your jsfiddle is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Aaron Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the roman numeral converter discussed in this question [Convert a number into a Roman Numeral in javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083037/convert-a-number-into-a-roman-numeral-in-javascript).
By example, the one from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-roman-numeral-converter:

```
function romanize (num) {
    if (!+num)
        return false;
    var digits = String(+num).split(""),
        key    = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM",
                  "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC",
                  "","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"],
        roman  = "",
        i      = 3;
    while (i--)
        roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
    return Array(+digits.join("") + 1).join("M") + roman;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var currentTime  = new Date();
var strRomanDate = romanize(currentTime.getMonth() + 1) + " . " + 
                   romanize(currentTime.getDate())      + " . " +
                   romanize(currentTime.getFullYear()) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
    document.write(toRoman(month) + " . " + toRoman(day) + " . " + toRoman(year))

function toRoman(num) {
    var listOfNum = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
    var listOfRoman = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', "C", 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I']

    var numToRoman = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < listOfNum.length; i++) {
        while (num >= listOfNum[i]) {
            numToRoman += listOfRoman[i];
            num -= listOfNum[i];
        }
    }
    return numToRoman;
}
```