# Algorithm to convert Roman Numerals with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to implement Algorithm which converts Roman numeral to Arabic with Javascript. Using the following suggested methods.

1. [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
2. [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
3. [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

I have already found the algorithm which solves this task

```
function convertToRoman(num) {

  var numeric = [ 5000,4000,1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1 ];
  var roman = [ 'V\u0305','I\u0305V\u0305','M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I' ];

  var output = '', i, len = numeric.length;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    while (numeric[i] <= num) {
      output += roman[i];
      num -= numeric[i];
    }
  }

  return output;
}

convertToRoman(4999);
```

Nevertheless i'm curious how to implement an algorithm with above mentioned methods.

Thanks, please do not judge me harshly, i'm a beginner programmer.

Comment: Why do you explicitly want to use these functions when your current solution seems fine (probably better than shoehorning some non-related functions into it)? Is this homework?

Comment: Because i want to understand how to apply these methods. No it is not a home work it is an algorithm from Free Code Camp.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question has already been answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083857/4269495

**Number to Roman Numeral:**

```
Number.prototype.toRoman= function () {
    var num = Math.floor(this), 
        val, s= '', i= 0, 
        v = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1], 
        r = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I']; 

    function toBigRoman(n) {
        var ret = '', n1 = '', rem = n;
        while (rem > 1000) {
            var prefix = '', suffix = '', n = rem, s = '' + rem, magnitude = 1;
            while (n > 1000) {
                n /= 1000;
                magnitude *= 1000;
                prefix += '(';
                suffix += ')';
            }
            n1 = Math.floor(n);
            rem = s - (n1 * magnitude);
            ret += prefix + n1.toRoman() + suffix;
        }
        return ret + rem.toRoman();
    }

    if (this - num || num < 1) num = 0;
    if (num > 3999) return toBigRoman(num);

    while (num) {
        val = v[i];
        while (num >= val) {
            num -= val;
            s += r[i];
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return s;
};
```

Comment: Then you mark the question as a duplicate.