# javascript find and replace just whole words in a textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text area with a list of roman numerals that I want to convert to arabic digits with a button click.  How can I replace only the whole numbers and not parts of the other numbers.  For example, I have:

```
XI
XXI
XXXI
```

and I get

```
11
X11
XX11
```

but I want

```
11
XXI
XXXI
```

The code I'm using is:

```
function romanToArabic() {

  var str = document.getElementById("textArea").value;

  var mapObj = {
    XI:"11",
    V:"5" 
  };

  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");
  str = str.replace(re, function(matched){
    return mapObj[matched];
  });

  document.getElementById("textArea").value = str;

}
```

I've seen various solutions with using \b but I can't figure out where to put it in my code.  Thanks.

Comment: can you varify `XI:"6"` assignment is correct? It shouldn't be `VI:"6"`

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake and corrected it.  I meant to put XI:"11".

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083037/convert-a-number-into-a-roman-numeral-in-javascript

Comment: You can’t do this with just string replacement – there’s math involved.

Comment: @pfg: that is the opposite of what’s being asked here

Comment: Actually, my question is not about converting roman numerals, it's about searching a text area and replacing only the whole word strings, not parts of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is add `\\b` to begin and end of the regular expression. It will match the whole word.

```js
function romanToArabic() {

  var str = document.getElementById("textArea").value;

  var mapObj = {
    XI:"11",
    V:"5" 
  };

  var re = new RegExp("\\b(" + Object.keys(mapObj).join("|") + ")\\b","gi");
  str = str.replace(re, function(matched){
    return mapObj[matched];
  });

  document.getElementById("textArea").value = str;

}
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
<br />
<button onClick="romanToArabic()">Convert</button>
```

Comment: Your solution is failing for this case: **XII** .It should print **XII** as it is but printing **11I** Please check it and make amendments accordingly

Comment: @Mandy8055 fixed

Comment: @Mandy8055 You're right.  I had it marked as correct, but then saw your comment

Comment: @user3080392 I have fixed it. What you need is wrapped the reg with `(` and `)`

Comment: @Daniel Tran Yes this worked well.  Thanks for giving an answer that incorporated the code I already had.

Answer (score 2):

I took your spec and made it "work", by:

- Defining the correct regular expression `\b[XIV]+\b` (matches a whole roman number)
- Use your object as a mapping function and a fallback if it fails, `mapObj[roman] || roman`

What the script doesn't do:

- Catch illegal roman numbers, i.e. it allows `XIIX`
- Implement a proper algorithm for the match, like `XV`, idealistically should parse to `10 + 5 = 15`

```js
function fromRoman(roman) {
  var mapObj = {
    XI:"11",
    V:"5" 
  };
  return mapObj[roman] || roman;
}

function convertFromRoman() {
  var str = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
  var output = str.replace(/\b[XIV]+\b/g, fromRoman);
  document.getElementById("output").value = output;
}

convertFromRoman();
```

```html
<p>Input:</p>

<textarea id="textArea" style="width:100%; height:50px" onkeyup="convertFromRoman()">
XI
XXI
XXXI
</textarea>

<p/>

<p>Output:</p>

<textarea id="output" style="width:100%; height:50px">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way , just split your textArea value by new line `('\n')`.

```js
var val=["XI", "XXI", "XXXI"]; // $("textarea").val().split('\n');
var outPut = [];
$.each(val, function(index, object) {
 if(object.length == 2){
   outPut.push(object.replace("XI",'11'));
 }else{
    outPut.push(object);
}
 console.log(outPut[outPut.length-1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```