# How can I break numbers into their digit values?

Tags: javascript, numbers, digits, roman-numerals

As part of a Roman numerals converter algorithm, I would like to break a given number into their digit values. What I precisely want to do is as follows:

```
1984 = 1000+900+80+4
```

It would be better to let you know where I will use the outcome. I will push the result in an array and match with their Roman numeral counterpart, e.g. 1000 = M, 900 = CM, 80 = LXXX, 4 = IV.

1984 = MCMLXXXIV

What kind of function is needed to produce the expected output?

Comment: apparently you can use this
https://blog.usejournal.com/create-a-roman-numerals-converter-in-javascript-a82fda6b7a60

Comment: My methodology differs from most of the others on the web, but this could also be a great use.

Comment: ok got it for the first part you can try this `a=1984;a1=String(a).split("").map((x, i)=>{return parseInt(x+"0".repeat(jash.length-i-1))})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083037/convert-a-number-into-a-roman-numeral-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a number into a Roman Numeral in javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083037/convert-a-number-into-a-roman-numeral-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked it into this one-liner:

```js
Array.from((1984).toString()).reverse().map((d, i) => d * 10 ** i)
```

This will give you the parts in reverse (least significant digit first); depending on your need you may want to add another `.reverse()` at the end.

Comment: let separator = (num) => {

  let array = Array
.from((num).toString())
.reverse()
.map((d, i) => d * 10 ** i)
.sort((a,b) => b - a )

return array; 

}

Comment: the `sort()` is overkill, you should just use `reverse()` : `let separator = num => Array.from(num.toString()).reverse().map((d, i) => d * 10 ** i).reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two small algorithms to do just that:

```
function separate(number) {
  const length = number.toString().length;
  const result = [0];
  let step = 1;

  for (let i= 0; i< length; i++) {
    step *= 10;
    let part = number % step;

    result.forEach(previous => {
      part -= previous;
     });

    result[i] = part;
  }

  return result;
}
```

and

```
function separate(number) {
  const str = number.toString();
  const result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result[i] = str.charAt(i) * Math.pow(10, i);
  }

  return result;  
}
```

It returns an array with each separated number

Comment: step *= 10; produces error due to its being a constant.

Comment: @MehmetEyüpoğlu you're right sorry I had these algorithms in C and I missed that when I transpiled them to JavaScript. Should be fixed now