# Function not being called onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

This code is a converter program. It takes a number from the `input` than converts with HTML romanize function. The function works with extraction operation. Take a number then extract some way.

I check a functıon. Functıon hasn't any problem when I send a string number to function like `romanize("1234")`, it works clearly. But I can't send with `input` element. The connection is also controlled. All elements can be selected and send a variable.

`convertNumberToRoman.onclick = romanize(inputNumber.value)` code didn't work. When I hit the button nothing happens. I want to enter a number in the input and click the 'convert' button then converted roman numbers show HTML.

```js
let inputNumber = document.querySelector("#inputNumber")
let convertNumberToRoman = document.querySelector("#convertNumberToRoman")
let displayRoman = document.querySelector(".displayRoman")
let div = document.createElement("div")

convertNumberToRoman.onclick = romanize(inputNumber.value)

function romanize(num) {
  if (parseInt(num)) {
    let digits = Number(num);
    let roman = "";
    while (digits >= 1000) {
      digits = digits - 1000;
      roman = roman + "M";
    }
    while (digits >= 900) {
      digits = digits - 900
      roman = roman + "CM"
    }
    while (digits >= 500) {
      digits = digits - 500
      roman = roman + "D"
    }
    while (digits >= 400) {
      digits = digits - 400
      roman = roman + "CD"
    }
    while (digits >= 100) {
      digits = digits - 100
      roman = roman + "C"
    }
    while (digits >= 90) {
      digits = digits - 90
      roman = roman + "XC"
    }
    while (digits >= 50) {
      digits = digits - 50
      roman = roman + "L"
    }
    while (digits >= 40) {
      digits = digits - 40
      roman = roman + "XL"
    }
    while (digits >= 10) {
      digits = digits - 10
      roman = roman + "X"
    }
    while (digits >= 9) {
      digits = digits - 9
      roman = roman + "IX"
    }
    while (digits >= 5) {
      digits = digits - 5
      roman = roman + "V"
    }
    while (digits >= 4) {
      digits = digits - 4
      roman = roman + "IV"
    }
    while (digits >= 1) {
      digits = digits - 1
      roman = roman + "I"
    }
    div.innerHTML = roman
    displayRoman.appendChild(div)
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="card row">
    <div class="card-header">Roman Numeral Converter</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form id="todo-form" name="form">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input class="" type="text" name="" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Enter a Number">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="convertNumberToRoman">Convert</button>
            <div class="displayRoman"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <hr>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="romanNumerals.js"></script>
```

Comment: Related question: [Convert a number into a Roman numeral in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083037/convert-a-number-into-a-roman-numeral-in-javascript) Yet, it's not a dupe since the current question is really about how form elements work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've hooked your event handler to the submit button. When this is clicked it submits the form and causes a page redirection.

To prevent this, hook your event handler to the `submit` event of the `form` instead. Then you can call `preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting, and also you can have the benefit of allowing users to press the return key in the `input` to trigger the function.

```js
let inputNumber = document.querySelector("#inputNumber");
let displayRoman = document.querySelector(".displayRoman");
let div = document.createElement("div");

document.querySelector('#todo-form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  romanize(inputNumber.value);
});

function romanize(num) {
  if (parseInt(num)) {
    let digits = Number(num);
    let roman = "";
    
    while (digits >= 1000) {
      digits = digits - 1000;
      roman = roman + "M";
    }
    while (digits >= 900) {
      digits = digits - 900;
      roman = roman + "CM";
    }
    while (digits >= 500) {
      digits = digits - 500;
      roman = roman + "D";
    }
    while (digits >= 400) {
      digits = digits - 400;
      roman = roman + "CD";
    }
    while (digits >= 100) {
      digits = digits - 100;
      roman = roman + "C";
    }
    while (digits >= 90) {
      digits = digits - 90
      roman = roman + "XC"
    }
    while (digits >= 50) {
      digits = digits - 50;
      roman = roman + "L";
    }
    while (digits >= 40) {
      digits = digits - 40;
      roman = roman + "XL";
    }
    while (digits >= 10) {
      digits = digits - 10;
      roman = roman + "X";
    }
    while (digits >= 9) {
      digits = digits - 9;
      roman = roman + "IX";
    }
    while (digits >= 5) {
      digits = digits - 5;
      roman = roman + "V";
    }
    while (digits >= 4) {
      digits = digits - 4;
      roman = roman + "IV";
    }
    while (digits >= 1) {
      digits = digits - 1;
      roman = roman + "I";
    }
    div.innerHTML = roman;
    displayRoman.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="card row">
    <div class="card-header">Roman Numeral Converter</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form id="todo-form" name="form">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input class="" type="text" name="" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Enter a Number">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="convertNumberToRoman">Convert</button>
            <div class="displayRoman"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <hr>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="romanNumerals.js"></script>
```

As an aside to the issue, note that your logic to Romanize the input value can be optimised. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083076/519413) for more details on that.